# What are the techniques of sharing data in Angular and its pros and cons

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, feedback

As far as I know, there are four ways of sharing data in Angular (we can see them [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#parent-component-ts-1)):

1. via `Input()` decorator;
2. via `ViewChild()` decorator;
3. via `Output()` decorator and `EventEmitter`;
4. using Services.

Are there other methods of sharing data between Angular components? What are its pros and cons?

Comment: Obviously the pros and cons depend on the particular problem you are trying to solve. I encourage you to read through the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs) and the many articles available to find out each one's strengths and weaknesses for yourself.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the particular problem, but in the same problem, we may use services or input. In my case, I'd prefer services because I'm familiar with it. An advantage using service is two-way data flow (parent to child and child to parent) and a disadvantage is that we must create an another `.ts` file. So I'd like to know others pros and cons (if exists) to give me other views to solve my problems.

Comment: You really need to understand how Angular is designed to work before pros and cons can be interpreted.  One pro of Input() and Output() is they allow for easy reuse of "dumb" components. One con of  services is that each component must have the same instance of the service. This can get hard to maintain when you are trying to communicate with components which are declared in different modules.

Comment: In my opinion, if you are using angular the way it was designed, services would hardly ever be used for component to component communication. Having said that, roll with it if its working until you discover it's limitations.

Comment: Wallace, thank you for your comments. Now I see some advantages of using `input()` / `output()`. I asked this question because I always use services and currently I'd want to try other ways. I like your "services would hardly ever be used for component to component communication" and from now on I'll try to use services less and less as possible.

Comment: Interesting conversation. I'm currently working on a course that talks to this topic (but have more than 4 techniques). `Input` makes sense if you simply want to pass a value from the parent to the child. Building a service just to pass in a default value or one configuration value seems like overkill. `Output` is great if the child component needs to send a notification that is caught by the parent's template. And `ViewChild` is great if you need access to the nativeElement (to set focus for example) or if you want to access the NgModel or NgForm (or any other directive) data structures.

Comment: @DeborahK, thank you for your comment. I changed the topic of this question and I would like to know if you can share with us others sharing data techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. It is a 5 hour course and would be very difficult to summarize in a Stackoverflow post. I don't know where I would even start ...

Comment: I'm putting together a summary slide. When I have it finished, I'll post it here ...

Comment: Thank you @DeborahK. It'd help me a lot to understand more about Angular sharing data.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between 1-3 and 4 item is about 'family'.

You can use 1-3 only if commponents have parent-child connection.

If components are not 'relatives' you should use servise